# Removing newlines and returns from HTML using Java

Tags: java

I am parsing HTML content using Java, and am trying to remove the \r\n from \r\n26.11.2012. I have used the following code in my program to try and remove the \r\n, but it does not seem to work.

```
attribute = attribute.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "");
```

How can this code be adjusted to convert \r\n26.11.2012 to 26.11.2012 ?

Comment: Can you add more detail about what isn't working?

Comment: Works fine for me, are you sure your not trying to remove the literal '\r','\n','\t'. Or is there another bug in your code you have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        TestCase.assertEquals("26.11.2012", "\r\n26.11.2012".replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", ""));
```

Your code actually works. This test case passes. Perhaps the input isn't what you expect or the attribute value is being processed on the way out and this has added the characters.